# Find employees whose supervisor's supervisor is a specific person

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to find all employees whose supervisor's supervisor has a SSN of '888665555'

I can't seem to figure out what I'm not doing correctly.

Here is a copy of the table being used.

```
Fname    Lname   Ssn       Super_ssn
john     smith   123456789 333445555
franklin wong    333445555 888665555
alicia   zelaya  999887777 987654321
jennifer wallace 987654321 888665555
ramesh   narayan 666884444 333446666
joyce    english 453453453 333445555
ahmad    jabbar  987987987 987654321
james    borg    888665555 NULL
```

The SQL code I've been trying is below.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.Fname, EMPLOYEE.Lname
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPLOYEE.Super_ssn =
(SELECT EMPLOYEE.Ssn 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPLOYEE.Super_ssn = '888665555');
```

The result should look something like this:

```
Fname  Lname
john   smith
alicia zelaya
ramesh narayan
joyce  english
ahmad  jabbar
```

Comment: Add expected result too, and it will be easier to assist you!

Comment: Expected result would John Smith. His supervisor is Franklin wong. wong's supervisor's SSN is 888665555

Comment: What problem do you encounter @IDOMATH ?

Comment: @NSNoob, when I execute the SQL, it tells me "At most one query can be returned by this subquery"

Comment: That's maybe because both Franklin Wong's supervisor and Jennifer Wallace Supervisor fields have 888665555 in it?

Comment: @NSNoob, how can I fix this problem then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to NSNoob.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.Fname, EMPLOYEE.Lname
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPLOYEE.Super_ssn IN
(SELECT EMPLOYEE.Ssn 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPLOYEE.Super_ssn = '888665555');
```

This takes each of the results instead of only accepting one.

Answer (score 3):

Your subquery below is returning more than one results.

```
(SELECT EMPLOYEE.Ssn 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPLOYEE.Super_ssn = '888665555');
```

Modify it like

```
 (SELECT top 1 EMPLOYEE.Ssn 
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE EMPLOYEE.Super_ssn = '888665555');
```

Or something like that which returns you only one result by subquery.

Comment: It's better to do IN sub-query instead. (Or EXISTS.)

Comment: @jarlh yep it is. been long years since I actually bothered with the queries myself. That's why I added "Or something which returns only one value".

Answer (score 1):

MS Access sql does not have recursive selection. however if you know the depth you can perform standard (double) joins. the question is will your supervisors have only one super supervisors?

if you have only two levels: try this query:

```
    SELECT 
    tbl_employee.fname,
    tbl_employee.lname,
    tbl_employee_supervisor.ssn,
    tbl_employee_super_supervisor.ssn
FROM
    (tbl_employee
    LEFT JOIN tbl_employee AS tbl_employee_supervisor ON tbl_employee.super_ssn = tbl_employee_supervisor.ssn)
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_employee AS tbl_employee_super_supervisor ON tbl_employee_supervisor.super_ssn = tbl_employee_super_supervisor.ssn
WHERE
    (((tbl_employee_supervisor.ssn) = '888665555'))
        OR (((tbl_employee_super_supervisor.ssn) = '888665555'));
```

result:

```
fname   lname   supervisor.ssn  super_supervisor.ssn
john    smith   333445555   888665555
franklin    wong    888665555   
alicia  zelaya  987654321   888665555
jennifer    wallace 888665555   
joyce   english 333445555   888665555
ahmad   jabbar  987654321   888665555
```

Comment: This will return the employee Franklin Wong. the OP needs the employee whose supervisor's supervisor has that ssn (Which is John smith). Thats why he is doing subquery.

Comment: @NSNoob still no reason to do a subquery. The only thing that needs to be changed it make the left joins inner joins and only leave the check for employee_super_supervisor in the where clause.

Comment: @GeertBellekens you are correct about where condition. just wanted to show the OP the variety of options he may have.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I wasn't defending the OPs logic. I was explaining to Krish here that why did the OP use it. He misunderstood that OP wanted to get employee whose supervisor's SSN was 888665555.